# Translate age() function from postgreSQL to Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm aware that age() doesn't exist in Google Bigquery. There's DATE_DIFF but it's not giving me the accurate difference between 2 dates.

For example, if run this query in postgresql

```
select AGE('2020-10-10','2000-10-11')
```

This will give me the result: **"19 years 11 mons 30 days"**

However, if I run this query in Google Bigquery

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(safe.parse_date('%Y%m%d', safe_cast(20201010 as string)),safe.parse_date('%Y%m%d', safe_cast(20001011 as string)), YEAR)
```

This will give me result: **20**

How can I achieve the result like in postgresql? That has the difference in **year, month, and day** between 2 dates in Google bigquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no direct function available in BigQuery using which you can get the output in the expected format, you can use [Javascript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) functions  which lets you call a Javascript function from a SQL query in BigQuery. For your reference, you can use the below sample query.

**Query:**

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  DiffinDate(days int64)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS r"""
 function DateDiff(days) {

var years = Math.floor(days / 365);
var months = Math.floor(days % 365 / 30);
var days = Math.floor(days % 365 % 30);

var yearsDisplay = years + (years == 1 ? " year " : " years ");
var monthsDisplay = months + (months == 1 ? " month " : " months ");
var daysDisplay = days + (days == 1 ? " day" : " days");

return yearsDisplay + monthsDisplay + daysDisplay 
 }
  return DateDiff(days);
 """;
WITH
  INPUT AS (
  SELECT
    DATE_DIFF(DATE '2010-07-07', DATE '2008-12-25', DAY) day )
SELECT
  DiffinDate(day) AS diff_in_date
FROM
  INPUT
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can change the calculation logic as per your convenience.